# android onclicklistener on class with button inside?

Tags: android, class, button, onclick

I made an app that creates 3 buttons dynamically. For certain reasons I needed to create every button from a class I made.

inside this class I wrote this:

```
public class FloatButton{
    public void generate(String text, final Context context){


        Button button = new Button(context);
        button.setText(text);
}
```

now in my main activity I create a object of this class:

```
FloatButton floatButton = new FloatButton();
floatButton.generate("float Button", this);
```

now to the problem... I  need to add an individual onclick listener to each button. I want to interact with other buttons of the class by clicking a button. That's why I need to write the onclick listener into my main activity and not into the FloatButton class. So I tried the following:

```
floatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

     }
});
```

this didn't work because the floatButton object doesn't have the setOnClickListener method because it is not part of the button class.

Also I tried to set an Id for the button inside the class. Therefore the class would look like this:

```
public class FloatButton{
    public void generate(String text, int id, final Context context){


        Button button = new Button(context);
        button.setId(id);
        button.setText(text);

    }
}
```

now I hoped to set the onclicklistener by the button id:

```
final OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
      case R.id.1:
        ...
        break;
      case R.id.2:
        ...
        break;
  }
}
```

Sadly the R.id. ... doesn't work neither because the Id is only available if the buttons are already created.

So what else can I try to do?

Comment: you have to use  interface technique in your button class to interact more efficiently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your generate function to

```
public Button generate(String text, final Context context){
        Button button = new Button(context);
        button.setText(text);
        return button;
}
```

then set listener on the **returned object** in activity

```
Button generated =  floatButton.generate("float Button", this);
generated.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

     }
});
```

Comment: fantastic! I didn't think about returning the button. I will try it out in a minute

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that like below:

```
public class FloatButton{
    private ClickListener listener;

    public void generate(String text, final Context context){
        Button button = new Button(context);
        button.setText(text);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listener != null){
                    listener.onClick(v);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void setListener(ClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick(View view);
    }
}
```

Activity class

```
FloatButton floatButton = new FloatButton();
floatButton.generate("float Button", this);
floatButton.setOnClickListener(new FloatButton.ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // You will receive all the generated button click events here in                 
        // single callback.
        // Do whatever you want to do here...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a getter to the button

```
public class FloatButton{

     private Button button;

     public void generate(String text, final Context context){
         button = new Button(context);
         button.setText(text);
     }

     public getButton(){
         return button;
     }

}
```

So after instantiating your floatButton object you can set the onClickListener using your getter

```
floatButton.getButton().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend your button class FloatButton from Button class like this

```
public class FloatButton extends Button {
public FloatButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public FloatButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public FloatButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public void generate(String text, final Context context) {
    FloatButton button = new FloatButton(context);
    button.setText(text);
}

//Rest of your methods
}
```

And you will be able to set onClickListener or anything you would normaly do with the regular button